Path-connected subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$
How would you show that $\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{C^2} : z_1\neq z_2 \}$ is path connected?
I tried to build up a path connected to pairs $(z_1,z_2)$ and $(z'_1,z'_2)$ by looking at different configurations (for example if the segment $[z_1 z'_1]$ intersects or not $[z_2,z'_2]$) but it seems complicated, is there a simple or direct way to show that it is path-connected?

I'm not sure if this helps, but I believe it's ${\mathbb R}^4$ with a plane removed, the plane being ${(x_1,,x_2,,x_3,,x_4) \in {\mathbb R}^4 : ; x_1 = x_3 ; \text{and} ; x_2 = x_4};$ if we identify via $z_1 = (x_1,,x_2)$ and $z_2 = (x_3,,x_4).$

Hint: Any two points in $\mathbb C^2$ belong to a common affine complex line. What does the intersection of such a line with your subset look like?

The space $\{(z_1, z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : z_1 \neq z_2 \}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C} \times (\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\})$ via the homeomorphism:
$$(z_1, z_2) \mapsto (z_1 + z_2, z_1 - z_2).$$
Using this identification, the fact that the set is path-connected becomes straightforward. Moreover, if you want a direct proof, you can use this identification to define the respective path between points.

Let $\gamma_r,\gamma_g,\gamma_b:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be the red, green, and blue paths in the image below. What you tried was $\gamma: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb C^2$ given by $\gamma(t) = (\gamma_r(t),\gamma_g(t))$, but this doesn't always work because the red and green curves might intersect (as they do in the image below) and so the two coordinates are equal there. However, if you take $\gamma': [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb C^2$ given by $\gamma'(t) = (\gamma_r(t),\gamma_b(t))$, then it is clear that the two coordinates are never equal. It is easy to see that you can find such non-intersecting paths between any two pairs of complex numbers, so your subset is path-connected.


I actually noticed that indeed it was possible to go around, but only with a drawing, not with an actual formal proof. How do you "easy see" formally that you can find such non-intersecting path. (How to prove the existence of the blue path formally, beyond just giving an example that works in that case)
